# Centos 7 firewalld changes source address for local connection

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, centos-7

I'm using CentOS 7 on my server. I have an application that accepts connections only from localhost. The problem is with firewalld that it changes local connection to use external address as a source connection. This makes the application to refuse the connection as it's not local.

Listen on port 4444 on localhost

```
 $ nc 127.0.0.1 -l 4444 -v
 Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
 Ncat: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Make connection to localhost

```
 $ nc 127.0.0.1 4444
 hello
```

Listening nc instance prints

```
 Ncat: Connection from external_address.
 Ncat: Connection from external_address:45274.
 hello
```

Here is firewalld configuration for trusted zone, where lo is

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --list-all
trusted (active)
  interfaces: lo
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Is it intended behaviour or a bug? Is there any simple solution how it might get fixed?

**EDIT**:

IP Address setting

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:7d:8a:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 173.234.39.178/29 brd 173.234.39.183 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 173.234.39.179/16 brd 173.234.255.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 173.234.39.180/16 brd 173.234.255.255 scope global secondary enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe7d:8a96/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:7d:8a:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.2.0.1 peer 10.2.0.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Routing

```
$ ip route list 
default via 173.234.39.177 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 100 
10.2.0.0/24 via 10.2.0.2 dev tun0 
10.2.0.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.0.1 
173.234.0.0/16 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 173.234.39.179  metric 100 
173.234.39.176/29 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 173.234.39.178  metric 100
```

Firewall configuration for trusted zone

```
 $ firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --list-all
trusted (active)
  interfaces: lo
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: I tried replicating your netcat example on a recently installed CentOS 7 machine with `firewalld`running at the time (using default configuration). The connection was reported as coming from 127.0.0.1 (as I'd expect).  I can't say why your network connections would appear to come from the non-loopback network interface.

Comment: It would be useful to [edit] the question to include the output of `ip addr show` and `ip route list` so we can see how IP networking is configured on your system.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Thanks for your response, I've added the ip address configuration and routes.

Comment: I've been thinking about your question for a while (as it's an interesting problem) but I can't see anything out of the ordinary with the scope of your network interfaces and routes. If you don't get any answers here, I'd suggest moving this question on [unix.se] where the expertise is more specialised, Don't cross-post, though. Either delete this version and re-post it there or flag a moderator to migrate it. Good luck.